# Meteor.js: Client doesn't subscribe to collection

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I created a little example for myself to test some stuff with Meteor. But right now it looks like I can't subscribe to a collection, I published on the server side. I hope somebody can tell me where the bug is.

**server/model.js**

```
Test = new Meteor.Collection("test");

  if (Test.find().count() < 1) {
    Test.insert({id: 1,
                 name: "test1"});

    Test.insert({id: 2,
                 name: "test2"});
  }

Meteor.publish('test', function () {
  return Test.find();
});
```

**client/test.js**

```
Meteor.subscribe("test");

Test = new Meteor.Collection("test");

Template.hello.test = function () {
  console.log(Test.find().count());//returns 0
  return Test.findOne();
}

Template.hello.events = {
  'click input' : function () {
    // template data, if any, is available in 'this'
    if (typeof console !== 'undefined')
      console.log("You pressed the button");
  }
};
```

**client/test.html**

```
<head>
  <title>test</title>
</head>

<body>
  {{> hello}}
</body>

<template name="hello">
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
  {{#with test}}
    ID: {{id}}  Name: {{name}}
  {{/with}}
  <input type="button" value="Click" />
</template>
```

**EDIT 1**

I want to change the object test, findOne() returns. Let's say for adding an attribute avg which contains the average value of two numbers (test.number1 and test.number2). In my opinion this should look like the following code. But javascript is not synchronous, so this won't work.

```
Template.hello.test = function () {
  var test = Test.findOne();
  test.avg = (test.number1 + test.number2) / 2;
  return test;
}
```

**EDIT 2**

This code worked for me. Now I have to rethink why this solution with 'if (test)' just works with findOne() without a selector in my original project.

```
Template.hello.test = function () {
  var avg = 0, total = 0, cursor = Test.find(), count = cursor.count();
  cursor.forEach(function(e)
  {
    total += e.number;
  });
  avg = total / count;

  var test = Test.findOne({id: 1});
  if (test) {
    test.avg = avg;
  }

  return test;
}
```

Comment: You want to change the value of record and push it to the server, right?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve here. It seems you are doing a lot of different things here, especially in the second example. Can you provide a simpler question?

Comment: I just wanted to add some attributes to the object from the collection and send it to the template engine.

Comment: Basically, with the reactive templates, the variables get refreshed every 5 or 10 seconds.  Your code looks like imperative script, but behind the scenes, it's getting constantly refreshed.  And what often happens is that the local client will render the page before it connects to the server.  So, by adding the if(test) clause, you're adding a circuit breaker to your logic for when the variable hasn't been reactively set yet.  Meteor code is kind of like quantum mechanics...  variables can be both set and unset at the same time (at least, as far as the imperative code statement is concerned.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to surround `{{#with test}}...{{/with}}` with `{{#if}}...{{/if}}` statement (because in first data push `test` does not have `id` and `name` fields):

```
<head>
  <title>test</title>
</head>

<body>
  {{> hello}}
</body>

<template name="hello">
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
  {{#if test}}
    {{#with test}}
      ID: {{id}}  Name: {{name}}
    {{/with}}
  {{/if}}
  <input type="button" value="Click" />
</template>
```

As a result:

[image: Resulting page]

**UPDATE**:

This code performs calculation of average of field `number` in all records:

model.js:

```
Test = new Meteor.Collection("test");

Test.remove({});

if (Test.find().count() < 1) 
{
    Test.insert({id: 1,
                 name: "test1",
                 number: 13});

    Test.insert({id: 2,
                 name: "test2",
                 number: 75});
}
```

test.js

```
Test = new Meteor.Collection("test");

Template.hello.test = function () {
  var avg = 0, total = 0, cursor = Test.find(), count = cursor.count();
  cursor.forEach(function(e)
  {
    total += e.number;
  });
  avg = total / count;

  return { "obj": Test.findOne(), "avg": avg };
}
```

**UPDATE 2**:

This code snippet works for me:

```
var test = Test.findOne(); 
if (test) 
{ 
    test.rnd = Math.random(); 
} 
return test;
```

Maybe you should try to wrap assignment code into `if` statement too?

Comment: Thanks fedosov! That worked for me. But I have another question in the same context which I posted unterneath.

Answer (score 3):

The latency the client db uses to replicate data might cause the situation wherein the cursor reckons no results. This especially occurs when the template is immediately rendered as the app loads.

One workaround is to observe query documents as they enter the result set. Hence, something like the following for example happens to work pretty well:

```
Meteor.subscribe("Coll");

var cursor = Coll.find();

cursor.observe({
  "added": function (doc) {
    ... something...
  }
})
```